# React: Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm experiencing this warning with different components in my application but I will take just the following one as example.

I have got the following component. It has a map function that renders multiple components from an array:

```html
const Clipboards = () => {
    const { user, addClipboard } = useAuth();
    
    const clipboards = user?.clipboards || [];
    return (
        <>
            {clipboards.map(clipboard =>
                <Clipboard clipboard={clipboard}/>
            )}
            <IconButton  onClick={() => addClipboard()} color={'secondary'}>
                <PlusIcon/>
            </IconButton>
        
        </>
    )
};

export default Clipboards;
```

with Clipboard being as follows. As you can see, I use key prop in the wrapping div:

```html
const Clipboard = ({clipboard, setSelectedClipboard}) => {
    const {addClipboardRubric} = useAuth();
    const {enqueueSnackbar} = useSnackbar();
    
    const selectClip = () => {
        setSelectedClipboard({id: clipboard.id, name: clipboard.name})
    };
    
    const [{isActive}, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
        accept: 'rubric',
        collect: (monitor) => ({
            isActive: monitor.canDrop() && monitor.isOver(),
        }),
        drop(item, monitor) {
            handleDrop(item)
        },
    }));
    
    const handleDrop = async (rubric) => {
        try {
            await addClipboardRubric({
                clipboardId: clipboard.id,
                rubric: rubric
            })
            enqueueSnackbar('Rubric added', {
                variant: 'success'
            });
        } catch (e) {
            enqueueSnackbar('Rubric already added', {
                variant: 'error'
            });
        }
        
    }
    console.log(`clip-${clipboard.id}`)
    return (
        <div ref={drop} key={clipboard.id}>
            <IconButton
                id={`clip-${clipboard.id}`}
                onClick={selectClip}
                color={'secondary'}
            >
                <Badge badgeContent={clipboard?.rubrics?.length || 0} color={"secondary"}>
                    <ClipboardIcon/>
                </Badge>
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    )
}

export default connect(
    ({search: {repertories = {}}}) => ({repertories}),
    (dispatch) => ({
        setSelectedClipboard: (payload) => dispatch(SET_SELECTED_CLIPBOARD(payload)),
    })
)(Clipboard);
```

As you can see. I'm adding the key and it is unique.
What would be the problem then?

[image: showing unique keys]

Comment: You need to add a key to your items returned from map funtion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a unique key to every item returned from the `map` function. For example, you can use the index as a unique key which is not recommended but just to give you an example. In your code, you are adding a key inside the component. You need to add the key to the component itself. Check the below code.

```html
const Clipboards = () => {
    const { user, addClipboard } = useAuth();
    
    const clipboards = user?.clipboards || [];
    return (
        <>
            {clipboards.map((clipboard,index) =>
                <Clipboard clipboard={clipboard} key={index}/>
            )}
            <IconButton  onClick={() => addClipboard()} color={'secondary'}>
                <PlusIcon/>
            </IconButton>
        
        </>
    )
};

export default Clipboards;
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added a key to the Clipboard component which is returned by the map.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Try something like this (if Clipboard as an id property):

```
{clipboards.map(clipboard =>
  <Clipboard key={clipboard.id} clipboard={clipboard}/>
)}
```

[Read this before using the index as a key](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318)